# How to return the index where values change in a c++ vector?

Tags: c++, vector

Sorry for the vague title, I'm not sure how to word it.

Say I have a vector:

```
vector<int> vec{{
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14
}};
```

and a corresponding positions vector which occurs after a number is missed (like 5 to 7).

```
vector<int> positions{{
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1
}};
```

How would I return a 2D vector running from each 1, up to but not including the next one: e.g.

```
1 2 3 4 5
7 8 9 10
12 13 14
```

Thanks in advance, I'd post my attempts, but they all led down blind avenues. I know it's an odd structure...

Comment: *I'd post my attempts*, no you didn't, and if you are creating one, you should not post this question.

Comment: Thanks for that, I said I would have added them, but they don't seem to be leading anywhere, so why include them and clutter things? I'm not being funny, but I wouldn't go to SO without having attempting it first because frankly it's not worth the hassle sometimes (evident here).

Comment: would you want an empty vector at the first row?

Comment: BTW, just post your broken code is fine.

Comment: Okay! Sometimes it seems it's just getting in the way, but I will in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to solve this, but I believe this should work:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec2D;
int index = -1;
// Identify the indices of the position vector and use that to identify the 
// correct indices of the vec. 
for (int i = 0; i != position.size(); ++i)
{
    // if the value at i of the position vector is 0, 
    // push_back the value at i of the vec vector into
    // the correct vector of vector.
    if (0 == position[i])
    {
        vec2D[index].push_back(vec[i])
    }
    else if (1 == position[i])
    {
        ++index; //increment to the next vector
        std::vector<int> temp;
        vec2D.push_back(temp);
        vec2D[index].push_back(vec[i])  
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that did work. The vector incrementing threw me a bit, so that bit really cleared it for me. Thanks.

Comment: @TW93 just a note, this would not work if the first item in `positions` is not `1`

Comment: Not to worry, I gathered that. The code before it is such that it must begin with 1